# Multiple breakpoints on one bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am looking for a way to use 2 different breakpoints in my BS4 navbar. A number of menu items should be always collapsed, while different menu items only collapse on -sm screens. So, in the example below, options 4-6 should always be collapsed and options 1-3 should be visible on screens larger than -sm, and **collapse into the same toggler** on -sm screens. Both parts should be right-aligned, next to each other.

It should look like this on large screens:
[Large screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaBRn.jpg)

And like this on small screens:
[Small screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOhQL.jpg)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbars">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 1</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 3</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="navbar2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 4</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 5</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 6</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have searched everywhere, but can't seem to find a solution. I have tried to combine two fixed-top navbars, but gives overlapping results when you click on the toggler. I have played around with '.navbar-collapse-sm' and similar classes, but that doesn't work either.

So is this even possible? Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would need to be some custom CSS to control #navbar1...

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #navbar1 {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-basis: auto;
    }

    /* prevent flicker during toggle */
    #navbar1.collapsing {
        transition: none;
        height: auto;
    }

    #navbar1 .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

And some changes to the navbar markup:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler order-sm-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbars">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-sm-0 navbars" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item pr-sm-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 1</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item pr-sm-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item pr-sm-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 3</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars order-last" id="navbar2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 4</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 5</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 6</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/pAhSgWkXcA